# Rendering a CSV file based on Form checkbox [RAILS 3.0]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def index
  unless params['excel'].blank?
    render_csv("patients-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}")
  else
    render
  end
end

 def render_csv(filename = nil)
    filename ||= params[:action]
    filename += '.csv'

    if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /msie/i
      headers['Pragma'] = 'public'
      headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain" 
      headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
      headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\"" 
      headers['Expires'] = "0" 
    else
      headers["Content-Type"] ||= 'text/csv'
      headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\"" 
    end

    render :layout => false
  end
```

I want it to use a different view and no layout, but I want to be able to reuse this function and not hard code a template... Any ideas?

(Right now I am getting html in my .csv file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a link and using

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv {render_csv("patients-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}")}
  end
```